# Azure "continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file" Cancelled unexpectedly

Tags: azure, debugging, speech-to-text

I have a same audio file ran 3 times and 2 times it stopped at the roughly same place. Is there something I can set to mitigate its occurrence? TIA

```
CANCELED at 0
CLOSING on SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=0ab1851d71e24ca2bd4f462ecdf9995a, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=1a5ecdd8b0af4acab0cf243657b1c3ee, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
SESSION STOPPED SessionEventArgs(session_id=0ab1851d71e24ca2bd4f462ecdf9995a)
CLOSING on SessionEventArgs(session_id=0ab1851d71e24ca2bd4f462ecdf9995a)

Total Time elaped  0:05:08.909569   From 2022-12-15 08:38:08.722855   To 2022-12-15 08:43:17.632424
```

Rerun and hope to get it through. Even I know it's not likely without knowing the root cause.